# Javascript - How can I get value from HTML return tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

In my project I have two Asp.net pages. The first is the main page and the second is the backend script page. When the user clicks the first page javascript will call the second page and should alert with a message like "Please confirm." but javascript is returning the whole html tag from second page. It doesn't return only error. How can I show the error from second page to render it in the first page? Please help me

1.Javascript code
http://www.mx7.com/view2/yCsMjYCaDlYctvSe

2.Return html whole second page
http://www.mx7.com/view2/yCsMmssWC8MkqLH8

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Ajax call `$.post` instead submit your form with form tag. This will fix your issue.

if you want to use `$.post` method change your server page to retun only alert data instead whole page.

Comment: if i want to use $.Post how can I set server page to return only alert data?